# iOS singleton class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, singleton

I am having a singleton class `MyController` of type `UIViewController`. I could able to access the view property like `[MyController sharedInstance].view` and could able to set that to `nil` like,

```
[MyController sharedInstance].view = nil;
```

I wanna restrict someone accessing view property. How could I stop/restrict that?

Comment: Why would you want the UIViewController to be a shared instance/singleton?

Comment: For reusing, I have a viewcontroller designed accordingly as a singleton and I am using that.

Comment: But what do you want to re-use?

Comment: I am using the controller in multiple screens. If the controller is created n number of times, it adds weight to the app. So, to overcome that, I am creating it once and reusing it every where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I overridden the method as

```
-(void)setView:(UIView*)view {
    if (view == nil) {
        //ignore - make no change
    }
    else {
        //default performance
        [super setView:view];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class ProjectSingleton {
        static let shared = ProjectSingleton()
        //here you can make any variable or function and use it anywhere in project
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> I am using the controller in multiple screens. If the controller is created n number of times, it adds weight to the app. So, to overcome that, I am creating it once and reusing it every where.

You can create a base class for your UIViewController that can be used across multiple views. iOS will handle the memory management correctly if you load a new view. The old view will be unloaded and

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

will be called. There you can dispose of any excess data.

Comment: I know the memory management stuff. I have architectured my app in such a way.

Comment: Then why would it be created n number of times?

Comment: It could obviously be created n times, but the previous instance should be deallocated when the next one is created. Reusing a UIViewController seems a very brave act to me. And being brave is _not_ what you want to be as a developer!

Comment: I know view controller's life cycle. Am not a newbie. Just trying that way.